# selinux can not be mounted on booting?

Tags: boot, mount, raspbian-jessie

I have a Pi B with Raspbian Jessie installed (upgraded recently from `wheezy` to `jessie` by changing `sources.lst`). I also use `rpi-update` to stay up to date.

On every boot I get as the very first message that `selinux` could not be mounted (file not found). However, in my `/etc/fstab` I can't find anything about "selinux". Only thing I have found was the folder `/etc/selinux` with a `semanage.conf`. The exact message is:

```
mount failed for selinuxfs on /sys/fs/selinux: No such file or directory
```

Grepping services results in:

```
# grep -i selinux /etc/init.d/*
/etc/init.d/checkroot.sh:       if selinux_enabled && [ -x /sbin/restorecon ] && [ -r /etc/mtab ]
/etc/init.d/udev:    # set the SELinux context for devices created in the initramfs
```

What is this selinux and how do I disable it so that it is not tried to be mounted on each boot? Or should I rather try to repair it (if it's important) so that it is mounted correctly (how would I do so)?

Comment: Does it cause any problem, or is it just a warning?   [Selinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) probably isn't enabled, but the functionality is likely included in the kernel so you can use it if you want.

Comment: No problems. Thing is, I don't want any garbage on my Pi (it's very stripped down, only the absolute minimum of what I need). And the stuff that is on my Pi should function correctly. Last but not least I want to learn. ;)

Comment: I definitely think this is just a kernel subsystem starting up then saying it has nothing to do.  Try and get that line exactly and paste it in; it's probably in `/var/log/syslog` and/or `/var/log/dmesg`; try `sudo grep -i selinux /var/log/*`.  I just checked my upgraded-to-jessie pi and there's nothing there, but it started out with a kernel I made which would not have anything selinux built into it.  I do have that `/etc/selinux/semanage.conf` file.

Answer (score 3):

[SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) is, as the wikipedia article says, "a mechanism for supporting access control security policies".  You probably don't need to do that on the pi as it turns out to be a bit of a hassle; it adds to the restrictions imposed by normal unix style permissions (file owner, group, etc.).

It probably isn't enabled either since you would likely have noticed some hassle, and I have not heard of it being enabled by default on Raspbian.  However, it may be built into the kernel in case you do want to enable the [userland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space) part; it's that module that's complaining when you boot up.

Edit `/boot/cmdline.txt` and add at *the beginning* of the line (it should only be one line):

```
selinux=0
```

Comment: Adding `selinux=0` at the very first entry did not do anything. It still is trying to mount SELinux as the very first boot actions, but can not because it does not find the path.

Comment: You should try and get the exact text of that error message.

Comment: I edited the question with the exact message.

Comment: It is very strange that `selinux=0` doesn't work *if* this is the kernel.   Are you sure you added it to `cmdline.txt` (not `config.txt`)?  Also, looking [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/672745/cant-boot-after-intrerrupting-do-release-upgrade-mount-failed-for-selinuxfs-on) I don't think it's really the first thing that happens, although it may appear to be.   Do a `grep "for selinuxfs" /var/log/syslog` and get the timestamp for that line, e.g. `[    2.202258]` <- number of seconds since kernel start.  Also `grep -i selinux /etc/init.d/*` to see if there is some service involved.

Comment: Edited question with `grep` results. Yes, double-checked, the `selinux=0` entry is in `cmdline.txt` as the very first content. The logs I have to check later.

Comment: Uh, how do I get `/var/log/syslog`? Do I need a specific package for it? I tried with package `bootlogd`, but it never writes to its own `/var/log/boot` either (it creates the file, however).

Comment: By default Raspbian uses `rsyslogd` to write *everything* to `/var/log/syslog`, so if you don't have that, something pretty odd is going on.   I've never seen a normative, stock linux not have that.  I have logged remarks about SELinux on some systems from when they were first booted up, before I added `selinux=0` to the kernel invocation.  I don't find *anything* on a wheezy pi or an upgraded-to-jessie pi though.

Comment: Whoops, forgot that I disabled these logs years back and switched to a more lightweight logger (`inetutils-syslog`)... Just installed it again, but it does not log any of the messages that appear on screen when booting. The message I am getting appears just below as the very first line under the Raspberry icon that is displayed while booting up. In the log I see however that `selinux=0` is active.

Comment: Sounds like you've painted yourself into a corner with a desire for "more lightweight".  *Did you actually evaluate rsyslogd at all first?*   Looking at a pidora B+ right now, it uses a whole **5 kb** of RAM.   If you mod the system in all kinds of zany, arguably pointless ways, understand that as it becomes more and more esoteric/eccentric, you are more and more on your own when it comes to problem solving...

Comment: Anyway, again, I still think you are being a little obsessive compulsive about one apparently harmless warning BUT if you are really determined, a better place to dig is [U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).   This really isn't a pi specific question at all.

Answer (score 0):

The likely reason for the problem is the installation of the `upstart` while `systemd` is present on the system.

A Proper solution will be to edit /boot/cmdline.txt and add `rw init=/bin/bash` at the end of the line, so it will look like:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait rw init=/bin/bash
```

Insert the card back into RPI and boot. Then you'll be able to remove `upstart` with:

```
sudo apt-get remove upstart
```

After that RPI should boot normally.